# JSSor slider - adjust caption width to image width

Tags: jssor

The images in my slider are not all of the same width. Is it possible for the caption to be of the same width as the image? 
Trying to get the image width dynamically, but it always returns 0:

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, function (slideIndex, fromIndex) {
    var _imgW = $('#img_' + slideIndex);
    $(".captionBlack").css("width", _imgW.innerWidth());
});
```

Every image has been assigned a unique id. Checking the dom at runtime shows the width and the var _imgW returns the correct element, but its width in the above snippet is always zero

---EDIT---

--markup--

```
<div id="slide_@i">
    <img id="img_@i" u="image" src="@roomAdvertImage" alt="@altImage" title="@altImage"/>
    <div u="thumb">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(@roomAdvertImage); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></div>       </div> 
@if (userPhotoTitle != null && userPhotoTitle.Length > 0){
    <div u=caption t="*" class="captionBlack"  style="position:absolute; left:0px; top: 30px; width:100%; height:40px;">@userPhotoTitle</div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: Please specify id for slide as well, and try var _imgW = $("#slide_" + slideIndex + " #img_" + slideIndex);

Comment: mmm...I've changed but it does not seem to affect it, width remains = 0. I've added the markup in the post (@i is an increasing variable since I'm looping a table for the images)